# Auth::attempt(['email' => Request::input('email') dont work?

Tags: laravel

I want to make auth with Laravel 5.0 but I entered true data or false data give the error

```
public function girispost(){
    //return  Request::input('email') .Request::input('password');
    // Auth::logout();`

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => 
        Request::input('email'), 'password' => Request::input('password')])) {
        return "giriş başarılı";
    } else {
        return "hatalı";
    }     
}
```

users table scheme

Comment: laravel save password with hash, first be sure your password set as a hash in your database and second be sure your input password is not hash and is plain charachter, i had this issue later

Comment: thanks i make hash password problem solved